# knockout.mapping not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have been using Knockout.js for a bit, and am now adapting a page to read json from the server. It was working until I switched to using knockout.mapping (to make things easier).

It renders (just once)

```
…
<p>hello <span data-bind="text: name"></span></p>
…
```

In the chrome debugger I see that `viewModel.rows()` is  `Array[4]`, but the 4 Objects appear empty.

What is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>

  <body>
    <div data-bind="foreach: rows">
      <!-- ko with: value -->
        <p>hello <span data-bind="text: name"></span></p>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
  </body>

  <script src="script/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="script/knockout.mapping-2.4.1.js"></script>

  <script>

var viewModel = null;

function load(){
    f = function(data) {
        if (viewModel == null){
            viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
        }else{
            ko.mapping.fromJSON(data,viewModel);
        }
    };

    f(
'{
   "total_rows" : 4,
   "rows" : [
      {
         "value" : { 
            "_id" : "e47b7701-cb51-4746-a02b-8a5203afa0a5",
            "name" : "alice",
            "_rev" : "13-327c79c92082537f7764b3d5601f1829"
         },
         "id" : "e47b7701-cb51-4746-a02b-8a5203afa0a5",
         "key" : 50
      },
      {
         "value" : {

            "_id" : "f450ccc5-3132-41a3-ade7-193d100e035b",
            "name" : "bob",
            "_rev" : "13-36dcb1ec370bcc27507b7d78ad66a5eb"
         },
         "id" : "f450ccc5-3132-41a3-ade7-193d100e035b",
         "key" : 100
      },
      {
         "value" : {
            "_id" : "c5bf17ce-f482-4bd7-a6c4-1b098aa213f8",
            "name" : "clare",
            "_rev" : "7-7b6acade5106e4b064249e7446dbc451"
         },
         "id" : "c5bf17ce-f482-4bd7-a6c4-1b098aa213f8",
         "key" : "0"
      }
   ],
   "offset" : 0
}'
    );
}

load();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle demonstrating your issue?

Comment: Do you want your nested object's (`value`) properties to be observable?

Comment: @PWKad http://jsfiddle.net/dqEXZ/

Comment: @rwisch45 Yes, at least I want the things in value to be observable. When I did a simple loaded without mapping it was not. I realised that mapping should be easier that writing the custom code I would have needed.

Comment: Another bug from simplifying to but as a question: strings can not span multiple lines.

Comment: No, not unless you escape the line break (which you can do by ending the line with a single `\` character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the JSON data as a string into the `f` function, not as a javascript object. Therefore you'll need to use `ko.mapping.fromJSON` instead of `ko.mapping.fromJS`.

Comment: Sorry that bug came in when I dragged the json into the code instead of fetching from server, when condensing code for question. (have fixed in question)

Comment: Good, now your code works perfectly fine for me, as long as I remove all new lines from within the JSON string, since you're not allowed to have line breaks in a JavaScript string, without escaping them.

Comment: Yes I just fixed that new line thing, and it worked. So it seems like it is just the bigger program that has the bug, and probably not the fault of knockout. Should not be difficult to debug now. Thanks.